# Cannot access Network and Sharing Center

Tags: windows-10, control-panel

On windows 10, when I type "Network and sharing center" in the start menu and click on the found entry, settings homepage opens:

[image]

When I try to click on the search result there, nothing happens at all:

[image]

I found this command which opens the settings:

```
control.exe /name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter
```

Why cannot I access the settings through normal menus?

Comment: Are you an Administrator on the machine?  What version of Windows 10 are you running?  What cumaltive updates do you have installed currently? Please edit your question to include this vital information.

Comment: Try to create another user profile and check if this also happens when logging with it.